# Why can a private class method be explicitly invoked in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, private

As we know, the private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver in ruby. But when I define a class, I can invoke a private class method by the class itself.

For example:

```
class A
   private
     def self.test
        puts "hello,world!"
     end
end

A.test => hello,world!
A.new.test NoMethodError: private method `test' called for #<A:0x007f80b91a10f8>
```

it is contradictory with the definition of private. Anyone can tell me the reason. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`private` only affects instance methods. To make a private class method, use `private_class_method`:

```
class A
   private_class_method def self.test
      puts "hello,world!"
   end
end
```

or

```
class A
   def self.test
      puts "hello,world!"
   end
   private_class_method :test
end
```

**EDIT:** Yet another way to do it is to define methods on the metaclass - they will behave as class methods.

```
class A
  class << self
    private
    def test
      puts "hello,world!"
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `protected_class_method` - but this last option gives us a hint on how to do it:

```
class A
  class << self
    protected
    def test
      puts "hello,world!"
    end
  end
end
```

but note that it can be only called from class methods of the descendant classes:

```
class B < A
  def self.test_class
    A.test
  end
  def test_instance
    A.test
  end
end

B.test_class
# => hello,world!
B.new.test_instance
# => `test_instance': protected method `test' called for A:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: @test: First option only works in newer Rubies, where `def` returns a symbol.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for your help, and protected also only affects instance methods?

Comment: @pangpang: Yes, `protected` also only affects instance methods. Added further examples on how to make protected class methods, if you really need them.

Comment: I just want to 100% confirm if I got what you were saying. You cannot define private class methods explicitly using private followed by the class method (i.e.: `private;def self.method;"x";end`)?

Answer (score 3):

`def self.test` declares a *class method*, not an instance method. To make class methods private you need to use `private_class_method`, not `private`.